# Find overlapping region contained in all polygons within single geodataframe

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I am trying to find a way to display only the overlapping region shared by all polygons in a geodataframe. My geodataframe includes polygon and multipolygon objects from a json file. The implementation I have now involves a loop to iterate over each polygon in the dataframe, however, this is very slow with large number of polygons and also it gives me every single pair of overlaps which is not what I want.

```
poly1 = Polygon((-119.74583075160622,  35.66006995660339), (-116.30697167993921,35.66006995660339),(-116.30697167993921,34.64381654506288),(-119.74583075160622, 34.64381654506288), (-119.74583075160622,35.66006995660339))
poly2 = Polygon((-118.33337318007834,34.66887933945114),(-117.85950530106018,35.64583276246657),(-117.46804922708861,35.34949851066835),(-116.97357839680875,35.50618853311429),(-116.49971051779052,34.43697449261936),(-116.7881518354538,34.52755087908893),(-118.33337318007834,34.66887933945114))
poly3 = Polygon((-118.73689979855544,34.71741592303824),(-118.0153587441971,35.95953776175309),(-117.45151590111556,34.512388830922866),(-118.27885217295977,34.67014942956098),(-118.73689979855544,34.71741592303824))
```

above are the contents in my gdf for this example.

```
overlaps =[]
for index, row in gdf.iterrows():
  for jindex, jrow in gdf.iloc[index+1:].iterrows():
    overlaps.append(jrow["geometry"].intersection(row["geometry"]))
```

There can be more than 3 overlapping polygons with a shared region, however, It can be assumed each additional polygon will share a common region and not be a outlier.

I would like it to show me the overlapped region within polygons (1 and 2 and 3) only. Not each pair: (1 and 2) (1 and 3) etc...

Is there a way where I can also use sjoin for the comparisons between each polygon since sjoin is faster?

Comment: how is an image data for a question?  plus why on some external site with nasty adware?   just add code to question of polygon construction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I can't confirm this, but theoretically you could chain intersections one after the other, using `functools.reduce()`:

```py
import functools
functools.reduce(lambda poly1, poly2: poly1.intersection(poly2), gdf["geometry"])
```

To make sure I understand the problem correctly, supposing you have polygons `A`, `B`, and `C` -- you want the intersection of all three?

If so, then my suggestion above *should* work, since intersection is associative, i.e., `A ∩ B ∩ C = A ∩ (B ∩ C) = (A ∩ B) ∩ C`.

Comment: Yes you understood correctly. What is functools returning exactly? Im playing around with it and it seems to return a string called "geometry" so I assume I need to convert it into a geodataframe?

Comment: Try now. If possible, could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post? I'd need your geometry data to test my solution.

Comment: Yes I will add what my polygons are, sorry I was originally just grabbing polygons straight from a json file so I forgot to include some poylgons in my post.

Comment: To answer your question, `functools.reduce()` returns an object of type `T` from an iterable of objects of type `T`, on which a closed binary operation (an operation of the form `(T, T) -> T`, i.e., takes two objects of type `T` and returns a single object of type `T`) is performed successively. An example would be summing a list of numbers: `reduce(+, (1, 2, 3, 4)) -> 1 + (2 + (3 + 4))` The `(3 + 4)` is evaluated to `7`, which is then added to `2` to get `9`, which is then added to `1` to get the final result `10`.

Comment: In this case, I'm assuming that `some_polygon.intersection(other_polygon)` returns another polygon object, which would be the "closed binary operation" necessary for this technique to work.

Comment: it worked, I forgot to include ['geometry'] in the proper spot. Thanks

Comment: Just a warning: if any two polygons *don't* overlap, you'll end up with an empty intersection, and the rest of your result will be empty.